# Как получить разницу времени?

Tags: php, время

Подскажите, как получить разницу во времени?
Например, есть два времени `14:15:00` и `15:00:00`, надо получить разницу и если разница меньше `59:00:00`, то тогда выполнить действие.
Пытаюсь сделать что то вроде:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('15:00:00 ');
$datetime2 = date_create('12:01:00');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
$time=$interval->format('%H:%i');
$send=date_create('00:59:00');
if($time<$send) 
{
 echo 'шлём';
echo '</br>';
echo $send;
}else{
 echo 'не шлём';
}
```

но $send оказывается почему то пустой...

Comment: Сутки всегда гарантируются одинаковые? Часовой пояс не имеет значения?

Comment: @andreymal, да, сутки всегда одинаковые, проверяется время текущего дня.

Answer (score 2):

Используй метод/функцию date_diff
http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php

Comment: к своему стыду, я не понимаю как вычленить разницу во времени, делаю что-то вроде этого:

Comment: Потому что нужно не time, а datetime. Подставь дату, хоть сегодняшнюю в свое время.

Answer (score 0):

Если это время в часах, минутах, секундах, то переводите все в секунды, отнимаете, и переводите обратно в нужный формат

```
sumsec1 = hour*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds; //Первое время в секунды
sumsec2 = hour*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds; //Второе
res = sumsec2 - sumsec1;
if (res > 59*3600) { выполнить действие }
```

Этот алгоритм можно использовать в любом языке помимо php